Como crear un XML con variados namespaces en Jakarta XML Binding (JAXB) Java
Tengo un problema al utilizar la librería Jakarta XML Binding (JAXB) en Java. Estoy creando un XML que contiene dos namespaces diferentes, uno para el elemento raíz Saa:DataPDU y otro para un elemento secundario . El XML debería lucir así:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Saa:DataPDU xmlns:Saa="urn:iso:std:20022">
    <!-- Contenido omitido para brevedad -->
    <Saa:Body>
        <AppHdr xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
            <!-- Contenido omitido para brevedad -->
        </AppHdr>
    </Saa:Body>
</Saa:DataPDU>

Sin embargo, al utilizar JAXB para generar este XML, el namespace head se declara en el nivel del elemento Saa:DataPDU en lugar de estar asociado con el elemento head:AppHdr. El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Saa:DataPDU xmlns:Saa="urn:iso:std:20022" xmlns:head="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
    <!-- Contenido omitido para brevedad -->
    <Saa:Body>
        <head:AppHdr>
            <!-- Contenido omitido para brevedad -->
        </head:AppHdr>
    </Saa:Body>
</Saa:DataPDU>

Esto ocasiona que el elemento head:AppHdr herede el namespace declarado en Saa:DataPDU, en lugar de tener su propio namespace asociado.
He intentado configurar el XmlSchema para evitar que se genere automáticamente un namespace para el namespace head, pero no he tenido éxito. ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo solucionar este problema y lograr que el namespace head se declare correctamente solo para el elemento head:AppHdr sin heredar el namespace del elemento raíz?
Adjunto clases Java
@XmlRootElement(name = "DataPDU", namespace = "urn:iso:std:20022")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DataPDU {
    @XmlElement(name = "Body", namespace = "urn:iso:std:20022")
    private Body body;
    
    // Getter y setter
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Header {
    @XmlElement(name = "Message", namespace = "urn:iso:std:20022")
    private Message message;
    
    // Getter y setter
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "AppHdr", namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AppHdr {
    @XmlElement(name = "Fr", namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02")
    private Fr fr;
    
    // Otros campos omitidos
    
    // Getter y setter
}

Tambien adjunto configuracion del XMLSchema
@XmlSchema(
    xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix = "Saa", namespaceURI = "urn:iso:std:20022"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "head", namespaceURI = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02"),
    }
)

Adjunto codigo de ejecucion tambien.
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataPDUDTO.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
File file = new File("src/main/resources/prueba.xml");


Tienes algunos elementos o attributos en el namespace head? Si quieres que el elemento AppHeader sea en el namespace urn:iso:std:20022 propongo que declares @XmlRootElement(name = "AppHdr", namespace = "urn:iso:std:20022")  en lugar del @XmlRootElement(name = "AppHdr", namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02")

El AppHdr tiene otro namespace distinto y tiene que ir sin prefijo, eso fue lo que me complicó al final y opté por ver otra librería. pude lograr esto con la libreria JDOM2.
